# Assign shortcut to macro/module in MS-Project?

Tags: vba, shortcut, ms-project

Is it possible to assign a shortcut to a module/macro in MS-Project? I was trying to use this code to create a shortcut Shift+Alt+D to my macro MyMacroD

```
Sub shortcut_D()
        Application.OnKey "%+{D}", "MyMacroD"
End Sub
```

But did not seem to work or maybe I placed it in a wrong place.

Comment: Is `OnKey` even a method of the Project `Application`? I couldn't find it in the object model docs.

Comment: Not sure. Just hoped that I could create more shortcuts than the very limited options that are not taken already. Maybe this is not possible.

Comment: Having to hit three keys doesn't seem like much of a "shortcut". Why not simply assign your macro to an icon on the quick access toolbar?